# Import list of dictionaries into python to convert to csv file

Tags: python, import, export-to-csv

I can find plenty of advice on converting  list of dictionaries to csv, but how to i get an external list of dictionaries which is a txt file into  python in the first place? I can bring it in as a file if the list is short -- say a dozen items -- but my list is several thousand items and i can't just paste it in or import as a file. Intuition suggests i should just bring it in and convert line by line, but how?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the contents of a text file in python in the following manner:

```
f = open('path/to/filename.txt','r') # r stands for read mode, also f is just an object here, NOT the content of the file
text_in_the_file = f.read()
```

This way you have all of the text in the .txt file as a string.
Now you can make use of the eval function to get dictionaries (or lists, tuples, anything else) from strings (it 'evaluates' the string to see what datatype it looks like). For example:`D = eval("{1:'a'}")` is the same as D = {1:'a'}.

So now you can use this information to perform your tasks.

Now it depends on in what manner you have stored those dictionaries in the txt file, most likely you'll have to use the split function. For example if you have one dictionary per line, you can:

```
txt = f.read()
list_of_dicts = txt.split('\n')
for i in list_of_dicts:
    D = eval(i)
```

Now do what you want with the dict! If you have any doubts, let me know and I'll see if I can help.